# Android: Debug Source Code in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging

I have an android project and I need to debug an android method of the view class, but when I try to step into the method it redirects me to a different method.

I'm running the project in my phone, which is running Android 5.0 (API 21) and in the gradle file I have the `compileSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion` both set to 21 and I also have the source code of the api 21 downloaded.

Does anyone know why the source code is not sync or has any tip that they can give me?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild and push it again? Also, are you getting any errors?

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. The code was not sync with the source code because my phone is a samsung and since samsung changes the source code on it's own, it was different from the code downloaded from the sdk manager. I tried it on a nexus and I was able to debug it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. The code was not sync with the source code because my phone is a samsung and since samsung changes the source code on it's own, it was different from the code downloaded from the sdk manager. I tried it on a nexus and I was able to debug it.